# How to detect cache misses from users codes?

Tags: performance, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux C++: how to profile time wasted due to cache misses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486840/linux-c-how-to-profile-time-wasted-due-to-cache-misses)

We have several users on the computing nodes which are running quite slow in some times.
Are there some utility which can tell that the code makes cache misses or give a some hints for the optimization?
The most of the users are coding in C++/C and F77/F90(some times with openmp).

Comment: For openmp, you could try KOJAK http://www.fz-juelich.de/jsc/kojak/components/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Those tools looks like mode developer tools rather than admin tools. I would like to make a quick test of the binary file and warn users about performance hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what operating system you are using you might want to look at [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/shark_optimize.html) (Mac OS X), [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com) (Linux) or [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/) (Windows).

Comment: The zoom looks interesting, thanks. I will try it.

Comment: @Arman: yes it's very good - you can get a free 30 day evaluation license in order to try it out - after that you have to buy it but it's very reasonably priced.

Comment: "Zoom" was much "solid" than Cachegrind from the Valgrind.